# overflow:auto not moving side margins

Tags: html, css

I am making an HTML website's index page now, and I don't know why this CSS isn't working.  My CSS code is as follows, and my HTML code after that:

```
body {
    background-image:url("background.png");
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

#content {
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:10px;
    width:60%;
}

.header {
    margin:10px;
}

.body {
    margin:10px;
}

.footer {
    margin:10px;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="header">
            <p>This is the header!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <p>This is the body!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>This is the footer!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, what ends up happening is that `overflow: auto` is not setting the side margins, but it is successfully setting the top and bottom margins.  Thanks in advance.

By the way, all of the images are also in the directory, and they are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `class` selectors in your CSS and `id` attributes in your HTML.

Either change your CSS to `#header`, `#body`, and `#footer`.

Or, change your HTML to `class="header"`, `class="body"`, and `class="footer"`.